# PHP & twitter API 1.1. Error in terminal

Tags: php, twitter

So, here is the error I'm getting on my .php file that is trying to grab tweets using the Twitter API 1.1. I have three files in my "TwitterMaster" file. I have the code to grab tweets from ESPN and the two required from Twitter Github. Here is what my line 3 looks like in my "HW.php" file

```
require_once("Users/Taylor/Desktop/TwitterMaster/twitteroauth.php");
```

Here is the error I am getting in mac terminal:

```
Taylors-Mac-mini:TwitterMaster Taylor$ php HW.php

    Warning: require_once(Users/Taylor/Desktop/TwitterMaster/twitteroauth.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/Taylor/Desktop/TwitterMaster/HW.php on line 3

    Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Users/Taylor/Desktop/TwitterMaster/twitteroauth.php' (include_path='.:') in /Users/Taylor/Desktop/TwitterMaster/HW.php on line 3
```

Any I do have cURL enabled.

Any ideas here? I've seen different answers talking about several things and don't know what to make of this.

Comment: this has NOTHING to do with curl: the error is very specific... the path you specified does not exist.

Comment: LIES MARC! LIES! haha But really, I'm looking at the file in front of me right meow. "Right click -> Get Info" and I see the folder path is the same in my code as well. Could it have something to do with the php.ini? That seems to be a thing for other people with similar problems.

Comment: you're specifying a relative path, relative to wherever that script is executing in. just because you can see it on your desktop doesn't mean that the script is looking from the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Good News Everyone!

I found out the answer. So it turns out I need to delete the "/blabla/bla/bla" in my code. It was the "/" that was causing terminal to try and look for the file `twitteroauth.php` everywhere. So by deleting all the forward slashes and simply put:

```
require_once("twitteroauth.php");
```

I was able to have the system just search for the file on its own, and since the first place it would look is the same file where the code originated from it was easy. AND this also makes the code more mobile. EVERYONE WINS! YEAAAHHH!!!!!

Stay in school kids!